# Do BASH Questions Belong on StackOverflow or SuperUser? Why?

Tags: discussion

I can see both sides:

- StackOverflow, because (1) programmers are *much* more likely to be able to relate to them and so be able to answer them, and (2) more often than not, the users who customize BASH are programmers, and (3) I've seen lots of BASH questions on StackOverflow.
- SuperUser, because (1) it's just a computer program and has nothing to do specifically with programming, and (2) I've seen some BASH questions on SuperUser too.

I've gone with the first option, and [it seems like there is agreement and disagreement on both sides](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480754/how-to-prevent-bash-from-altering-history).

Should there be something with regards to this on the FAQ or somewhere? Also, where should such a question go, *and **why***?

Comment: I'm guessing a bit here, but wouldn't [Unix.se] be an even better place for those questions?

Comment: @Anna: Kind of, but then what about Cygwin/MSYS/etc.? I guess those are kind of Linux/Unix too... not sure, no idea actually.

Comment: @Mehrdad SuperUser if the usage isn't programming related, SO otherwise? Programming tools are safely on topic on SO.

Comment: @Anna: Well... for my question, is that programming related or not? I'm certainly using BASH for programming right now, but that doesn't mean it's restricted to that. (What aspect of BASH ever be restricted to programming?)

Comment: @Mehrdad Your question I think belongs on SU (or, well, UL), since it doesn't have anything to with bash scripting and is about general use of the shell itself.

Answer (score 6):

Bash questions related to either bash scripting or programming issues with bash are kosher on Stack Overflow.  Your question is not programming-specific and thus does not belong on Stack Overflow but on either SuperUser or Unix and Linux.

Comment: Er... so you're saying the moment you put your commands in a file named `script.sh` and say `sh script.sh`, the same thing it belongs on SO instead of SU, just because it's scripted?

Comment: Yes, that's a rather important distinction.  Not to mention that doesn't apply to your question which is just about the mechanics of use and not even commands.

Comment: Yeah that definitely doesn't apply to my question, I agree -- just wanted to understand what you meant more generally. Hm... ok I guess... not too convincing but I guess it makes some sense.

Comment: @Mehrdad Interactive use of a shell is done by computer users, not by programmers, so it belongs on SU (or U&L or AU if applicable). Shell programming is programming, but it's an extension of what users do on a command line; shell programming questions can be asked on SO, SU, or U&L or AU when applicable.